# validations message culture

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to display messages in portuguese in errors displayed by jquery validator.
My web.config is:

```
<globalization culture="pt-BR" uiCulture="pt-BR" />
```

so why I asp.net mvc keeps showing english messages like:

```
The field Data must be a date.
```

Isn't globalization enought to asp.net mvc understand that I want portuguese messages?

---

Update

I tested my project in two different computers, in one the translations works, in the other don't. So, do I need to install something in my server?

Answer (score 2):

I just played around with this some and it is definitely setting the thread culture and thread UI culture correctly.  I also looked in the MVC source code, where the resource file (WebPageResources.resx) for the default messages lives.  It looks like there is only an English version of the resource file in the project (which is actually in the System.Web.WebPages project).  I'm not sure if they publish localized resources for MVC, but that would be the best place to start.

Alternatively, you can create your own resource file, and specify it in on the attribute, which is working correctly for me.  It's a little verbose though to percolate the entire project.

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(MyResourcesClass), ErrorMessageResourceName = "My_Required_Error_Message")]
```

Comment: It is very weird because yesterday the translations was working and the only thing I did was to put the globalization in web.config.

Comment: Hmm, in that case it might be something happening inside of asp.net which I don't think is open source.  I'd suggest emailing or tweeting this question link to someone on the asp.net mvc team and seeing if they can help you.